# Dynamic graphs as alternative representation of ODEs?

Tags: graph-theory, dynamical-systems

Recently, I started to deepen graph theory and what I found [here](http://www.ejpam.com/index.php/ejpam/article/download/1901/323) was really interesting for me. I mean, authors explain how they "transform" the predator-prey dynamical model in a dynamic graph, but at the end of the paper they remark that the method is not completely appliable. Thus, I would ask if there is a systematic way to pass from a system of differential equations (particularly, nonlinear ones) to a dynamic graph and viceversa.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I tried to understand what is in the link but the paper gives almost no information (at least that can be described as rigorous). Could you perhaps indicate a reference that discusses something related at a rigorous level (even if **only** linear **as** in the link)?

Comment: [This paper](http://www.malayajournal.org/articles/MJM011.pdf)
seems to be more rigorous than the first I have cited.

Comment: Thanks, will have a careful look at it.